# How do you prevent a development branch in Github from syncing to AppHarbor

Tags: github, appharbor

I have a master and a development branch in Github and the repository is configured to sync changes to AppHarbor.  I configured the master branch as specified at the [support site](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/deploying-your-first-application-using-git).

Is there a way that I can isolate the development branch and only push from the master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppHarbor will build all branches which is great for [Continious Integration purposes](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/09/06/github-commit-status-api-now-supported). You can specify what branch to deploy off by [setting the tracking branch](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  You guys provide great services.